# Setting colorbox highlight and node area for musix environment using Beamer with Musixtex

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minted, musixtex

It is needed to set colorbox highlight and node area for musix environment using Beamer with Musixtex, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}%Fuente tipo mano para pizarra en Beamer
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%Paquetes para Beamer
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{adjustbox}%Para centrar tablas
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
% set text colors for different objects
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}
%% set fonts
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}
%% Green Background Colour
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!18!black}
%% Random Dust Trails
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, \the\paperheight); 
      \foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{random(0,10000)/5000-1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{random(0,10000)/10000-0.1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,10000)/1000-5}%
            \rotatebox{\r}{
                %\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\x\paperwidth}{\y\paperheight}, left, base]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LOGO_UNDAR_PNG_RGB.png}}
            }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%% use a small dash ('-') for a bulletpoint list
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{item}\small\ECFAugie{-}}
%% Frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \vskip17pt
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle \\
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%% remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%% Date in the Corner
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \rotatebox{30}{
        \ifx\insertdate\empty\else        
            \hspace*{0.25cm}\ECFAugie\insertshortdate\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \fi
    }
    \vspace*{-1cm}
}

\begin{document}
\ECFAugie

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
    \frametitle{\LARGE Codificando una partitura en Musixtex}
    \normalfont    
        
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
    \begin{minted}[
        frame=lines,
        framesep=2mm,
        baselinestretch=1.2,
        bgcolor=gray,%gray-undar,
        fontsize=\footnotesize,
        linenos,
        escapeinside=@@,
        highlightlines={2}%,highlightcolor=red
        ]{latex}
    \begin{music}
     @\colorbox{yellow}{\setclef1\treble}@ % Clave de la partitura
     \nobarnumbers % Omite numeración en compases
     \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
     \NOTEs\ql a\qu c\ql e\en\setdoubleBAR 
     \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music}
    \end{minted}
    %};
    %\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,scale=1,fill=white] (EjemClave) at (0,0) {
        \scalebox{0.73}{\begin{music}
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de la partitura
        \nobarnumbers % Omite numeración compases
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \NOTEs\ql a\qu c\ql e\en\setdoubleBAR 
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music}}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
        
\ECFAugie   
            
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

Note that is needed to highline a code line part using Beamer and Minted package. Also is needed to extend the plotting area of the node using Beamer and Tikz package.

Comment: Can you clarify what changes you'd like to make to the yellow square?

Comment: You can make the white box on the right bigger with `\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,scale=1,fill=white,minimum width=4cm]`

Comment: Regarding the yellow square, I handle it with the following code:  @\colorbox{yellow}{\textbackslash{setclef1}\textbackslash{treble}}@ % Clave de la partitura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According feedback, It has been solved using the following code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}%Fuente tipo mano para pizarra en Beamer
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%Paquetes para Beamer
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{adjustbox}%Para centrar tablas
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
% set text colors for different objects
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}
%% set fonts
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\huge, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large, series=\ECFAugie}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\ECFAugie}
%% Green Background Colour
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!18!black}
%% Random Dust Trails
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, \the\paperheight); 
      \foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{random(0,10000)/5000-1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{random(0,10000)/10000-0.1}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{random(0,10000)/1000-5}%
            \rotatebox{\r}{
                %\pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\x\paperwidth}{\y\paperheight}, left, base]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LOGO_UNDAR_PNG_RGB.png}}
            }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%% use a small dash ('-') for a bulletpoint list
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{item}\small\ECFAugie{-}}
%% Frametitle
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{frametitle}
        \vskip17pt
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
        \insertframetitle \\
        \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
%% remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%% Date in the Corner
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \rotatebox{30}{
        \ifx\insertdate\empty\else        
            \hspace*{0.25cm}\ECFAugie\insertshortdate\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \fi
    }
    \vspace*{-1cm}
}

\begin{document}
\ECFAugie

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
    \frametitle{\LARGE Codificando una partitura en Musixtex}
    \normalfont    
        
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
    \begin{minted}[
        frame=lines,
        framesep=2mm,
        baselinestretch=1.2,
        bgcolor=gray,%gray-undar,
        fontsize=\footnotesize,
        linenos,
        escapeinside=@@,
        highlightlines={2}%,highlightcolor=red
        ]{latex}
    \begin{music}
     @\colorbox{yellow}{\textbackslash{setclef1}\textbackslash{treble}}@ % Clave de la partitura
     \nobarnumbers % Omite numeración en compases
     \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
     \NOTEs\ql a\qu c\ql e\en\setdoubleBAR 
     \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music}
    \end{minted}
    %};
    %\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,scale=1,fill=white,minimum width=4.5cm] (EjemClave) at (0,0) {
        \scalebox{0.73}{\begin{music}
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de la partitura
        \nobarnumbers % Omite numeración compases
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \NOTEs\ql a\qu c\ql e\en\setdoubleBAR 
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
    \end{music}}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
        
\ECFAugie               
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

The solved output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Comment: \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%Color boxes start with a small but noticeable space, which can be annoying when highlighting whole lines of Python where indentation matters, this command prevent it.